# Django Models relation with primary key add extra "_id" to the column

Tags: django

These are my two models, when I try to open City page on Django I get an error: "column city.country_id_id does not exist". I don't know why python adds extra `_id` there.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=3)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'country'

class City(models.Model):
    city_id=models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=3)
    city_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    country_id = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'city'
```

[image]

Comment: You should post the code that causes the error. "when I try to open City page on Django" doesn't help at all.

Comment: I think the error is not here!! You should consider adding some more code from where you are querying the database.

Comment: Because if you construct a foreign key, Django will construct a "twin field" that stores the primary key of the object. The foreign key itself is thus more a "proxy" field that fetches the object.

Comment: it was an extra '_id' Django automatically added, I did not know that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you construct a foreign key, Django will construct a "twin field" that stores the primary key of the object. The foreign key itself is thus more a "proxy" field that fetches the object.

Therefore you normally do *not* add an `_id` suffix to the `ForeignKey`:

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=3)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'city'
```

It however might be better for *unmanaged* tables, to specify a [**`db_column=…`** parameter [Djang-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column) in the `ForeignKey`:

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=3)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, db_column='country_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'city'
```

With this parameter you make it explicit how the column is named at the database side.

Comment: This solved my issue. '_id' automatically added. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

this is due to Django's behind the scenes magic.
The fields documentation is very clear about that and I highly recommend you read the Foreign Key section in the link below:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Basically, when you want to access the Country reference in the if a City instance, you would do it like this:
`city.country_id`

I also recommend another naming convention for your Foreign Key fields. Instead of `<modelname>_id = models.ForeignKey...` just call it `<modelname> = models.ForeignKey...`

Hope this helps, happy coding